# Is there a publicly available Gliese Star List

Tags: star

Is there a publicly available list of the Gliese catalogue of nearby stars with their constellations? or a Gliese to Hipparcos List ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliese_Catalogue_of_Nearby_Stars might help (note that it's Gliese, not Gilese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gliese catalogue can be found at CDS [here](http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/Cat?V/70A).

Given an RA and Dec then you can use the fortran program found [here](http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/Cat?VI/42) to get the constellation.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I finally got round to downloading and looking.  I ran the program and don't know what values i'm supposed to be entering.  What is meant by :-  CONSTELLATION derived from POSITION for Equinox and  Enter the position (HH.hhhh+DD.dddd).  How do I put in the following Star coordinates :- RA:06.45.08.9173, Dec: -16.42.58.017, returns Monoceros rather than Canis Major (Sirius)?

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser Its asking for decimal hours and degrees as input. Try 06.7525-16.7161. (hh.mm/60+ss.s/3600.0 , dd.mm/60+ss.s/3600.0).